# use of decode in oracle for two arguments

Tags: sql, oracle

Scenerio is that:

```
decode(rslt1,
       'stores',('stores,dead store'),
       rslt1);
```

Explanation: if my `rslt1` is equal to `stores` then `rslt` should be `stores` and `dead store`. Mean two arguments against one argument.

If there is anyother way kindly let me know?

Comment: Could you show how you'd use that construct, i.e. what would be the expected output in a sample query?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't been over-generous with the context but I presume you mean to use this in a WHERE clause.

I probably would use DECODE (or CASE) here but go for a normal filter:

```
 select *
 from your_table     
 where ( ( rslt1 = 'stores' 
            and rslt = 'dead store') 
          or rslt =  rslt1 )
```